# why constant variables are not treated as compile time constant sometime

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, stdarray

I tried to execute two different scenarios :

**Scenario 1:**

```
const auto arraySize = 10; // fine, arraySize is constant 
std::array<int, arraySize> data;
```

Here , arraySize is treated as compile time constant and hence it was allowed in std::array .

**Scenario 2:**

```
int sz=10;
const auto arraySize = sz; // fine .
std::array<int, arraySize> data; //error , arraySize is not compile time constant .
```

In scenario 2 , arraySize is not treated as compile time constant despite of the fact that arrySize is a constant copy of sz .

**Why these two scenarios were treated differently ?**

Comment: `arraySize` is a constant copy of something that is *not* constant...?

Comment: Because `const` doesn't mean "compile time constant". In certain cases it can be compile-time, but it's not guaranteed and therefore you cannot use them in contexts which require compile-time constants. Use `constexpr` instead!

Answer (score 3):

Because it can be like

```
int sz = 0;
std::cin >> sz;
const auto arraySize = sz;
```

and here value of `sz` is defined in runtime. You can use `constexpr`, instead of `const`, than will be compile error on such initialization.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should consider using `constexpr`.

`int sz=10;` is a *variable* set to some constant. The compiler may be clever enough (or not!) to constant propagate it when optimizing.